# POST request from Google Scripts to AWS Lambda coming through as null

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-apps-script, aws-lambda, http-post, aws-api-gateway

I'm attempting to send a POST request from a Google Sheet, containing a given row's data, using Google Apps Script. That request is to an AWS API Gateway, which sends it along to a Lambda function which then does some other things.

The AWS side all works when I use curl to send requests manually, but for some reason when I attempt to do it programmatically inside Sheets, the API will only pass null events to my function. The POST requests appear to be well formed when I print them out on the Sheets side, but my API refuses to pass them through. I know this because I have it set to log all events passed to the function in CloudWatch, and the automatic calls all just print {} as the event.

There's no authentication required in the API, so I can't imagine it being an auth issue. I also saw a common solution being to enable Lambda Proxy Integration, but I don't understand why curl would work if that were the issue.

I built my API using [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/services-apigateway-tutorial.html) almost exactly, if that's helpful.

Here's the relevant bit of code from the Apps Script side:

```
/**
 * Creates JSON payload and sends request to Amazon. 
 */
function sendRequest()
{
  const url = "https://**********.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/prod/DynamoDBManager";

  // Make a POST request with a JSON payload.
  var data = 
  {
    "operation": "create",
    'tableName': 'lambda-apigateway',
    'payload': {
      'Item': {
        'name': nameGiven,
        'contact': contactGiven.toString(),
        'id': currId.toString()
      }
    }
  };

  var options = 
  {
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
  };
  
  var response =  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  var jsonObject = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); // just makes the response visible in debugger
}
```

Comment: Although I'm not sure about your each value of the data, I think that the request of your UrlFetchApp is required to be modified. So, when you modified `body: JSON.stringify(data),` to `payload: JSON.stringify(data),`, what result will you obtain? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: @Tanaike this fully fixed it! thank you. if you post an answer i'll mark it as solution.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I posted it as an answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your script, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
body: JSON.stringify(data),
```

#### To:

```
payload: JSON.stringify(data),
```

#### Reference:

- [UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)